# manipulate marshaller in jax-ws

Tags: jax-ws, cdata

is there a way to manipulate the marshaller used in jaxws. 
I like to send a cdata filed in a webservice request and for this i want to try something like describet here: http://odedpeer.blogspot.de/2010/07/jaxb-sun-and-how-to-marshal-cdata.html

in short they does this:

```java
Marshaller m = JAXBContext.newInstance( Item.class ).createMarshaller();  
m.setProperty( "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.characterEscapeHandler", new CharacterEscapeHandler() {  
  @Override  
  public void escape( char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag, Writer writer ) throws IOException  
  {  
   // do not escape  
   writer.write( ac, i, j );  
  }  
});
```

is this possible with jaxws somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to your question is:

`JAX-WS` is based on `JAXB` so yes, it is possible, just create `JAXB` related stuff (as you showed in your question) in your application and you'll be able to process `XML` from your request in your web service.