# How to tell JAX-WS to escape apostrophe on request?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

## Problem

I want my JAX-WS-Client to escape the single quote (apostrophe) `'` to be escaped as `&apos;` when sending a request. In JAXB this can be done by implementing your own CharacterEscapeHandler and setting it like:

```java
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), new MyCharacterHandler());
```

But I have not found a way to get the JAXB-Context of a JAX-WS-Request.

## Things I tried

1. Adding above jaxb-property via SOAPHandler

This didn't change the output in any way:

```java
        lHandlers.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
                Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
                if (outbound.booleanValue()) {
                    try {
                        context.getMessage().setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(),
                            new XmlCharacterHandler());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            [..]
        });
```

2. @XmlJavaTypeAdapter

The value is changed before escaping kicks in, so that the actual output will be `&amp;apos;` because the `&` in `&apos;` will be escaped.

## Things I found

- Similiar question here but with no answer about the **how**:
  [manipulate marshaller in jax-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907855/manipulate-marshaller-in-jax-ws)
- This comment indicates (contrary to the above) that this isn't possible:

  > I have confirmation from IBM that it is not possible to set properties on JAXB marshaller of JAX-WS/RS runtimes of IBM.

  from here: https://coderanch.com/t/628709/certification/set-properties-JAXB-Marshaller-JAX

Comment: Have you find a solution yet? I am having the exact same problem

Comment: No sorry, we managed to change the serverside code so that we don't need the fix from above anymore.

Comment: I've managed to get the request value into a CDATA object, so we've had it resolved now